How to get tsig history for domains?
I want to maintain a local list of tsig DNS updates for all domains on my DNS, so that there's some form of 'authentication' so I can avoid MITM attacks. For instance, whenever I get a TXT record under google.com, any of my local laptop's cached DNS values for google.com should only update to the new DNS record if I can also verify the tsig value that Google used for the DNS record update. Is there any way to get such signatures, or any archive of such signatures, or ways to sniff them in real time by operating as a DNS relayer or server or something?
Sorry if this is a little naiive, I have seen RFC3645 about tsig, but am still unsure if DNS zone servers are just trusted to give authoritative answers after they verify tsig -- I want to verify the tsig myself and am willing to run any infrastructure to get as many tsig signatures as possible for as many domains as possible, as I really want to avoid any MITM attacks on my server.

There is no such thing.
For one, DNS in general is not made to keep update history; the only version available from typical DNS servers is the current version. (About the only extent of changes kept in standard operation is what's needed for the authoritative servers to sync more efficiently.)
This also applies to TSIG; the signatures are there only to authenticate the client that issues the update – not the data itself – so they are discarded as soon as the operation has been applied.
Second, not all DNS changes are done through TSIG dynamic updates – that's one possible mechanism, but by no means a mandatory one. For example, it is just as common to have a static zone file that is updated with vim /var/named/example.com.db, or to have the zones hosted on a separate database that is updated through custom API or other means – like, say, an LDAP directory that holds the DNS records for an Active Directory domain, or a Postgres table that holds DNS records for all GoDaddy customers.
At the scale of Google, for example, it's almost guaranteed that they do not use TSIG-based updates; they most likely have some sort of internal API that authenticates clients using TLS or ALTS certificates (and puts records in BigTable) where the DNS servers will pick them up. On the other end of the spectrum, half my own DNS zones are static files that I keep in a Git repository (the other half are updated using GSS-TSIG). Most of the world is somewhere in the middle, where they use web interfaces to submit updates via HTTP that go into MySQL or Postgres.

Sorry if this is a little naiive, I have seen RFC3645 about tsig, but am still unsure if DNS zone servers are just trusted to give authoritative answers after they verify tsig -- I want to verify the tsig myself and am willing to run any infrastructure to get as many tsig signatures as possible for as many domains as possible, as I really want to avoid any MITM attacks on my server.

You cannot verify TSIG signatures, because they are not the kind of signature you're thinking of – standard TSIG updates use HMAC, where the same key is used for both 'signing' and verification, therefore the key has to remain secret for TSIG to work at all.
(There is a public-key-based mechanism called SIG(0) but hardly anyone uses it even speaking relatively to other TSIG forms.)
That aside, TSIG is simply not designed to be a long-term signature and does not authenticate data in itself; its job is to authenticate the client that issues the operation (and only by extension, data in the operation), i.e. it's similar to TLS(-PSK) in function.
For example, the operation may still contain data that would be rejected later by server policy, so even having the key you still cannot meaningfully verify the operation without knowing how the server was configured at that specific time – whether that key was authorized to perform any updates at all (TSIG can also be used for queries), whether it was authorized to update that specific name with that specific value, etc.
What you're looking for – a long-term signature over the actual data – is provided by DNSSEC, typically with the signature being applied after the update has been accepted. (Though DNSSEC was designed to support offline signing of whole zone files, but these days it's more common to let the DNS server sign them online under the assumption that it is trusted.)
If the zone you're interested in is DNSSEC-signed, and with the assumption that its authoritative servers are trusted (e.g. they replicate the updates securely between each other), you can get the RRSIG signature records for each domain or subdomain (as well as "proof of absence" NSEC records) and verify them on your side. This is most likely already built into whichever DNS resolver software you're using – e.g. BIND and Unbound can both be set to validate RRSIGs on every query.
(Again, however, not all DNS zones are actually signed – if they aren't, you get whatever you get. This may improve with the very recent work on "authoritative DoT", which expands TLS MITM protection to the communications between your resolver and the authoritative servers, but it'll still take a while for that to spread.)
